# fixed position vuetify alert component

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, alert

I'm trying to create an alert component in VueJS/nuxtjs that will model the behavior of a snackbar (in this case fixed-bottom position, where it is fixed at the bottom when we scroll, so we see the alert as we're scrolling.)

For some reason I couldn't find much documentation on it. I've gone thru the alert component API on vuetify, and compared it to the snackbar component, but still can't seem to figure out why it's not working.

I've tried changing the position to absolute and it works, but for some reason instead of being fixed-bottom as the page scrolls it's literally fixed at the bottom and the user can't see the alert until they scroll down to the end of the page... when I use a snackbar component it works just fine, but I like the icon that alert comes with, hence the reason for using that component instead. I'll attach the code for the alert, as well as its parent component:

parent:
 `<div class="help-center-page max-w-none">`

alert component:

```
<div class="text-center">
      <v-alert :dismissible="true" prominent type="error">
        This is an alert.
      </v-alert>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The following CSS in the <style> section worked for me:

```
.v-alert {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 50px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0 auto;  // Without this the box extends the width of the page
}
```